# return the line number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to return the line number in my code, for example I want when I write `console.log('SomeCode');` in the line 33 to return 33.

How can I do that in JavaScript?

I googled about it and I found this code :

```
try{
  throw new Error('Buck stops here')
}catch(e){
  console.log( e.line)
}
```

But I don't want to use any try catch in my code.

Comment: Finding it from the stack trace is the only way.  Try-catch is a valid construct, why don't you want to use it?

Comment: @Emissary I think the intent was to avoid the try / catch in his example, which in that case the try / catch is redundant since you could just assign the Error object to a variable instead of throwing and catching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skip the try / catch and just use the Error object:

```
var x = new Error("I want the line number");
console.log(x.lineNumber);
```

More information is available at the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)

Also note that proprties like `lineNumebr` are implemented in specific interpreters and is not universal across all browsers.

Comment: When I tried this I got Indefined in console, I think the lineNumber property is valide on Firefox and Opera and not Google Chrome, because I'm using Google Chrome

Comment: if it is not available in your environment you might have to do your own regex parsing of `x.stack` to find it. There might be some snippets out there that do this.

Answer (score -1):

you need to catch all unhandled exceptions in your code. By doing this you won't need to put "try-catch" construction in.

```
window.onerror = function myErrorHandler(errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
    console.log("Error occured: " + errorMsg + " on line " + lineNumber);//or any message
    return false;
}
```

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)

Comment: This feels like a code smell. It could easily mask legit runtime errors you might expect to throw.

Comment: Agreed. You can throw an error in this block if you want. Depends what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: While this technique may be useful in some circunstances, This is awful advice for the question asked.

Comment: I re-read the question and now I see that I didn't get it right ;)